# How to change global navigationBar background color?

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

I want to change global background color of navigationBar. How can I do this?

The line:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.green
```

in `application(_:, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` doesn't work, while:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red
```

works correctly.

Comment: UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use Tint color in this case:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.green
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]

    return true
}
```

> iOS applies tint color to app icons, tab bars, navigation bars and many
> other things.